# I want to show traffic in google maps and to hide it with the same button

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio

I want to **show and hide traffic** (toggle) with the same button. So I tried the  `(onClick)` method in my XML and my Java code is:

```
public void traffic (View view){

    ImageButton bttn=findViewById(R.id.traffic);

    if(bttn.isClickable()){
        mMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
    }

    else {
        mMap.setTrafficEnabled(false);
    }
```

But this does not work. It only shows traffic and if I press the button again nothing happens.
How can this be fixed?

Comment: Could be that the button is always _clickable_.

Comment: Did you make the button not clickable anywhere?

Comment: its clickable,yes

Comment: If it is always _clickable_ ... How could the traffic ever be set to disabled?

Comment: i tried it with out clickable as well , but it only shows traffic !!!!

Answer (score 2):

I think you're confusing `clickable()`. The `clickable()` if always true, will never disable your traffic.

You should try this code to solve this problem, first declare a global variable like this:

```java
int clickcount=0;
```

```java
yourbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        clickcount=clickcount+1;
        if(clickcount%2!=0)
        {
            //first time clicked to do this, so enable traffic

        }
        else
        {

            //disable traffic here 

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help,but it only works for the first and second click ....if i tried it with the third click or the fourth , it doesn't show any traffic !!!!      I want to make it like ( click show traffic click don't show traffic) !  got it ??? :)

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
//global variable
 private boolean showTraffic = false;

ImageButton bttn=findViewById(R.id.traffic); 
bttn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    showTraffic = !showTraffic;
    if(showTraffic){
      //this is where you show Traffic
    }
    else{ 
      //this is where you hide Traffic
    }
}
 });
```